# Fetching data and associated image separately asynchronous and link them

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview, alamofire

When a user search I fetch some data from one source and based on what I receive I'm using another source to get an associated image. This is happening asynchronously. There is a specific image for one search result(Usually I get 4-6 results that I need to get image for).
It have happened that an image get linked with the wrong result data, mainly because it's happening async and my code doesn't handle that very good.

Take a look here

1. Search result gives 5 results
2. In collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath i fetch an image for each results and add it to the cell's imageView.
3. Sometimes the image can get misplaced

I believe I can add the image to the results array, but I need a way of linking the image and the right result data together.

What do people usually do?

Edit:
Doing an asynchrequest to fetch image.

```
func willReturnBookCoverFromNB(url: String, completionHandler: (imageD: NSData?, error: NSError?)-> ()){

    let safeurl = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
   let task =  Alamofire.request(.GET, safeurl!).response { (request, response, data, error) in
        print(request)
        print(response)
        if(error != nil){
            completionHandler(imageD: nil, error: error)
            return
        }else{
            completionHandler(imageD: data, error: nil)
            return
        }


    }
    task.resume()
}
```

In the collectionView:cellforRowAtIndex

```
bookImage.willReturnBookCoverFromNB(baseUrl, completionHandler: { (imageD, error) in
                        if error == nil{
                            //There is no error. Must be a image then..
                            let imageData = UIImage(data: imageD!)

                            cell.bookCover.image = imageData
                        }else{
                            let alert = displayAlert("Error!", text: "\(error!)")
                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    })
```

The collectionView and search result data will reload every time a user type in the searchField.

Comment: There are lots of ways to handle this. Post your code that is submitting the requests. Typically you'd use an async framework like NSURLSession, where you can provide a completion closure. The completion closure can see the index of the item being fetched from it's enclosing scope and put the image in the correct spot in your data model.

Comment: So are you saying that if the NSUrlSession is in a loop and try to get 5 images and append each image to an array at the index for when the NSurlSession request was fired in the loop. Will the images always be added in the right index they where requested in the loop?

Comment: You can create arrays of struct from async completion, where struct contains properties: imageName, url and a **lazy var imageData**. When asked by visible row the lazy var will will fetch image data and return it to UIImageView.

Comment: If you write your code correctly, yes, you can install your images into an array as the completion handler fires. You should probably add items to the array from the main thread to avoid concurrency problems. All that being said, though, loading images into an array is going to create a lot of memory stress. Better to save the images to local files on disk and then load them into memory as needed for each cell.

Comment: I made a loop now, but the index get's out of range before the image can be added to the array. Any pointers? I'm going to change the code to write the images to the cache folder, but I need pointers to make the index not get out of range before I can add a reference to the array.